# Avada - Theme options not working?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm working on a website with the Avada WordPress theme.
Currently I'm trying to change the theme options, so that my page title bar, where my breadcrumbs are located, will have a light gray background color. I have set this in the theme options as shown below but it's not changing after I save.

[image]
I changed this box from the blue color as shown in the link below, to white, but the background color still stays white. I also added the following code in the Custom CSS tab but that's not working either:

```
.fusion-page-title-bar{
background-color:white!important;
}
```

Example page: https://cryptokickoff.nl/cryptocurrency/bitcoin/
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It used to work.